# Restoring all rights for root

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have root access to the database on VPS, however it looks like root has no rights.

When I tried to create a database, it said :'`user 'root' access denied to database..'`

When I wanted to select users from mysql.users it said

```
'SELECT command denied to user 'root'
```

I wrote `'SHOW GRANTS'`, it gave 
`'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>'` in 'GRANTS FOR **'root@%'**' column

Ideas?

Comment: OS "root" is totally indepent of MySQL's "root".

Comment: `USAGE` means recognizing the name; it does not provide any privileges.  How did you get to where you are?

Comment: Can you explain what is that and how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/2761/change-password

Comment: Change password? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, writing

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
```

connectiong to >mysql without username and -p.

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting?  Is the client on the same machine?  Same client?  You *seem* to be coming in from a different machine.  `%` is the world; you do *not* want root to get in that way.

If this is a Cloud setup, you were probably told what IP address to come in from, and that may be the only way to come in.

We need to know who set up your access and the details (except password).

Comment: It's a VPS. I'm connecting remotely via the IP. Login is 'root'.

Comment: Mysql was updated. May it be the reason?